# Jupyterlab Kernel Restarting when running pytorch-related codes. Error "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically."

Tags: pytorch, kernel, jupyter-lab, pytorch-dataloader

**System:** Windows with Jupyterlab in Anaconda

I am running an imaging annotation cnn in Jupyterlab from Anaconda. Everything worked fine until yesterday I ran the same code, and the kernel shows "*Kernel Restarting  The kernel for address/Unet.ipynb appears to have died. It will restart automatically.*"

Line-by-line debugging found that in a new kernel, if I run **"import torch"** prior to **"import skimage.io"**, it crashes the kernel and it shows "*Kernel Restarting*". However, if I run **"import skimage.io"** prior to **"import torch"** everything works fine. So I

In another file running Unet segmentation, it also crashed during a long for a loop.

I have the below temporary solution worked, but I also want to know why it happened and whether there is a way to solve the issue once and for all. I read a few similar questions and found it could be a Torch or version issue. Thank you to anyone who contributes!

**Tried the below code and worked (so far):**
import os
os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK']='True'

**Tried the below codes but were unluck:**
Create a new environment and start over
Confirmed CPU/GPU... is not out of memory
reinstalled pytorch, pytorch-cuda, torchvision,torchaudio,
conda update torch torchvision
conda update scikit-image
conda update mkl
conda update --all
conda install numpy
conda install -c intel mkl
conda install tensorflow
conda install -c anaconda keras
pip uninstall mpi4py
Update Anaconda